# PHP Regex matches pattern separately on the same line

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a text with php regex. I wrote a pattern match with everything in line. I do not want it. It must match the target **separately on the same line**.

the pattern:

```
/\((?P<type>\w+)((,)*(?P<params>[\d\w\:]+))((,)*(?P<comment>.*))\)/u
```

---

target data string:

```
lorem ipsum dolor (photo,61) test (photo,62,some text) (video,63) sit amet etc
```

---

results preg_match_all with PREG_SET_ORDER flag:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => string '(photo,61) test (photo,62,some text) (video,63)' (length=47)
      'type' => string 'photo' (length=5)
      1 => string 'photo' (length=5)
      2 => string ',61' (length=3)
      3 => string ',' (length=1)
      'params' => string '61' (length=2)
      4 => string '61' (length=2)
      5 => string ') test (photo,62,some text) (video,63' (length=37)
      6 => string '' (length=0)
      'comment' => string ') test (photo,62,some text) (video,63' (length=37)
      7 => string ') test (photo,62,some text) (video,63' (length=37)
```

---

If the target data is placed in separate lines and same regex pattern execution results; (I want these results but without new lines)

```
lorem ipsum dolor 
(photo,61) test 
(photo,62,some text) 
(video,63) sit amet etc

array (size=3)
    0 => 
        array (size=11)
          0 => string '(photo,61)' (length=10)
          'type' => string 'photo' (length=5)
          1 => string 'photo' (length=5)
          2 => string ',61' (length=3)
          3 => string ',' (length=1)
          'params' => string '61' (length=2)
          4 => string '61' (length=2)
          5 => string '' (length=0)
          6 => string '' (length=0)
          'comment' => string '' (length=0)
          7 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => 
        array (size=11)
          0 => string '(photo,62,some text)' (length=20)
          'type' => string 'photo' (length=5)
          1 => string 'photo' (length=5)
          2 => string ',62' (length=3)
          3 => string ',' (length=1)
          'params' => string '62' (length=2)
          4 => string '62' (length=2)
          5 => string ',some text' (length=10)
          6 => string ',' (length=1)
          'comment' => string 'some text' (length=9)
          7 => string 'some text' (length=9)
      2 => 
        array (size=11)
          0 => string '(video,63)' (length=10)
          'type' => string 'video' (length=5)
          1 => string 'video' (length=5)
          2 => string ',63' (length=3)
          3 => string ',' (length=1)
          'params' => string '63' (length=2)
          4 => string '63' (length=2)
          5 => string '' (length=0)
          6 => string '' (length=0)
          'comment' => string '' (length=0)
          7 => string '' (length=0)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not know what you mean

Comment: What you mean by without new lines can you please elaborate

Comment: @Uchiha For example, moving to a new line with the Enter key. Programatically: \r\n. This character is available, it works but I want to work when it is not.

Comment: Try this `'~\(.*?\)~'`

Comment: just use this .*?\\) it will fill your need

Comment: @Uchiha empty array returned.

Comment: @İsmailCeylan [Check This](https://eval.in/409519)

Comment: @Uchiha okay, done. held out, but it was fix. Can I force my chances? Is it possible within a single pattern?

Comment: @İsmailCeylan Can't get you.

Comment: @Uchiha no there is a way, I wrote. I handle single pattern and explode the parts to the arrays. thanks for your helps.

Comment: @İsmailCeylan You're welcome (_FYI: You can accept an answer or upvote an answer which really helps you._)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use instead

```
'~\(.*?\)~'
```

and it'll be done

[<kbd>**Regex101**</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/xA9sU3/3)
[<kbd>**Eval**</kbd>](https://eval.in/409561)

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution not affected newlines (radical solution is to enclose with "~...~" not using "/.../")

```
~\((\w+),([\d|:]+),*(.*?)\)~u
```

---

named version;

```
~\((?P<type>\w+),(?P<params>[\d|:]+),*(?P<comment>.*?)\)~u
```

---

Thanks for @Uchiha pre-solution and Thanks for the hint given.

```
'~\(.*?\)~'
```